# How to solve Error: Compile Error: Field is not writeable error for ListPrice Field on opportunity Line Item

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem, compile-error

I am trying to assign the List Price field on `OpportunityLineItem` to 0 using trigger but receiving the Compile Error as:

> Field is not writable error.

```
for(OpportunityLineItem oli: trigger.new) { 
    oli.ListPrice=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the List Price is a formula which comes from the Pricebook Entry [Opportunity Line Item Documentation from Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm)

Comment: So should i need to update the price book entry ?I want to make this value to 0 always for few record types

Comment: Be careful with the language you use, Record Type has its' own meaning in Salesforce.com. If you want the OpportunityLineItem to have a default price of 0 dollars, you should set the price in the Standard Pricebook for that Product at 0 dollars.

Comment: I would recommend taking some more Admin / Sales Cloud trail heads to familiarize yourself with Opportunities, Pricebooks, Products, and  OpportunityLineItems before diving into Apex with them.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, a more appropriate field to set for the price of an individual `OpportunityLineItem` is the **`UnitPrice`** field, which is specific to that single `Opportunity`, not the entire `Pricebook`.